# Disabling and enabling click event on image...jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

what would be the best way to enable and then re-enable and image click with jquery?

I can diasble the click event easy enough

```
$(document).on("click", "#rightPager", function () {

if (condition) {
    $(this).click(false);
  }
});
```

how would I go about in 'enabling' the click event again based on a certain condition?.

I would want to enable the button again for example

```
$(document).on("click", "#leftPager", function () {
$("#rightPager").click(true);

});
```

Comment: i dont really get your question.
Do you mean you want to disable the actuall onclick event from time to time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to rebind you would need to use the original .on("click") event again.

Write a function to bind an event to your image:

```
function bindImage() {
  $(img).on("click", function() {
   // Your bind event goes here
  });
}
```

Then write a conditional to unbind the event on the image if your condition returns true, then if its false, rebind the event to the image as normal.

```
if (condition) {
  $(img).unbind();
} else {
  bindImage();
}
```

Alternatively, you could complete this within a single function such as:

```
$(document).on("click", "#rightPager", function () {
  if (condition) {
    // terminate the function
    return false;
  } else {
    // put your function here to run as normal
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [jQuery off method](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ejcsf81/)

```
$(document).off('click', '#rightPager');
```

**Full code:**

```
var condition = true;

$(document).on("click", "#rightPager", function () {

    if(condition){

        alert('Click was disabled');
        $(document).off('click', '#rightPager');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you disable the default event by:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    condition ? doSomething() :  doSomethingElse();
});​
```

so basically is not that you enable then disable, you prevent the default action, check for your condition and they execute appropriate function